# Read from mutiple excel and write to one file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read data from multiple xls files and write it to one single file.

My code below is writing only the first file. Not sure what I am missing.

```
import glob import os import pandas as pd


def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return r  

files = list_files("C:\\Users\\12345\\BOFS")

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    new_header = df.iloc[1]
    df = df[2:]
    df.columns = new_header  
   
     with pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\12345\\Test\\Test.xls", mode='a') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer,index=False, header=True,)
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
In particular, clearly specify what you think you're missing.

Comment: `files = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\12345\\BOFS\\**\\*.xls',recursive=True)`

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) says:

> ExcelWriter can also be used to append to an existing Excel file:
>
> ```py
> with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',
>                     mode='a') as writer:  
>     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_3')
> ```

And that probably replaces given sheet

But you could use `pd.concat(<dataframes>)` to concatenate dataframes and write all data at once in a single sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this piece of code, hopefully its work in your case.

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("D:/Data Science/stackoverflow")
for file in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
  df = pd.read_excel(file)
  all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)

# now save the data frame
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
all_data.to_excel(writer,'sheet1')
writer.save()
```